# How to set the proxy_protocol to 'on' in a conditional manner in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

Any one familiar with nginx? I am trying to enable proxy_protocol in a conditional manner in a stream block ie for certain endpoints I want the proxy protocol header to be added. For others I dont want to add it. Looking at the documentation there is no way for proxy_protocol to take a variable (Tried the map directive) Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Added my nginx conf here.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol

This is the problematic piece `proxy_protocol $proxy_state;`

```
   map $ssl_preread_server_name $proxy_state{
        default on;
        facebook.com off;
    }
    server {
        listen 8443 ;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;        
        proxy_pass $server;
        proxy_protocol $proxy_state;
        ssl_preread on;

    }
```

The following is the complete config

```
error_log logs/error.log;

events {
}


stream {

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $server { 
        # default 127.0.0.1:8080;
        default unix:/var/run/nginx.sock;
        include /home/user/allow_url_list;

    } 
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $proxy_state{
        default on;
        facebook.com off;
    }
    server {
        listen 8443 ;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;        
        proxy_pass $server;
        proxy_protocol $proxy_state;
        ssl_preread on;
        
    }
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080 ssl;
        listen 80;
        listen unix:/var/run/nginx.sock ssl proxy_protocol;
        set_real_ip_from unix:;
        real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        include /home/conf/ssl-params.conf;
        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass https://$host$request_uri;
        }
       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split it into 2 servers. you can try if it works. Proxy protocol might cause problems.

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $internalport {
     facebook.com 10443;
     default 8443;
  }

server {
       listen 8443 ;
       resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;        
       proxy_pass $server;
       proxy_protocol on;
       ssl_preread on;
   }

server {
       listen 10443 ;
       resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;        
       proxy_pass $server;
       proxy_protocol off;
       ssl_preread on;

   }
```